# Filter records using a comma separated string

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

I've a string variable `@IDS` and I'm trying to filter the records from table `user` but nothing helping me out since I'm new to MySql.

```
SET @IDS = '1,2,3';
select * from user where find_in_set(@IDS,ID);
```

Comment: How hard is it to read the manual yourself, to make sure you're using a function correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the order of the parameters:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ID, @IDS);
```

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

> FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)
>   Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings

In other words, the first parameter is the string you are trying to find in the CSV list of strings which is the second parameter.  If `ID` can be found in `@IDS`, then the index (beginning at one) which matches will be returned.  If no match be found, then zero will be returned.